Can't Set headers After They are sent to the client
So I was working on my personal project and for some reason my nodejs part of the applications keeps crashing. I dont know the reason i have been trying to find the error in the code but so far their is not particualr progress.
The Error is -
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:406:5)        
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:652:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\devgarg\Downloads\Projects\React Projects\CENACLE\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:776:10)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\devgarg\Downloads\Projects\React Projects\CENACLE\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:264:10)
    at PassThrough.<anonymous> (file:///C:/Users/devgarg/Downloads/Projects/React%20Projects/CENACLE/server/controller/post.js:32:17)
    at PassThrough.emit (node:events:526:35)
    at PassThrough.emit (node:domain:488:12)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\devgarg\Downloads\Projects\React Projects\CENACLE\server\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:590:14)
    at Request.callListeners (C:\Users\devgarg\Downloads\Projects\React Projects\CENACLE\server\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (C:\Users\devgarg\Downloads\Projects\React Projects\CENACLE\server\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:78:10) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT',
  time: 2024-04-24T17:46:46.189Z
}

Node.js v20.9.0

It shows that the error is in server -> controller -> post.js at line 32.
The Function where the error shown is fetching the images from AWS S3 Bucket and sending them to the client end. I tried stop sending response if the same request is performed again. But it didnt resolve the issue.
let readStreams = {};

export const getPost = (req, res) => {
    const Key = req.path.split('/')[1];

    // If there is a read stream in progress for this key, destroy it
    if (readStreams[Key]) {
        readStreams[Key].destroy();
    }

    readStreams[Key] = getFile(Key);

    // Flag to check if response has been sent
    let responseSent = false;

    // Handle errors
    readStreams[Key].on("error", (err) => {
        if (!responseSent) {
            res.json({ error: "An error occurred while reading the stream" });
            responseSent = true;
        }
    });

    // Pipe the stream to the response
    readStreams[Key].pipe(res);

    // Close the stream after it's finished processing
    readStreams[Key].on("end", () => {
        if (!responseSent) {
            readStreams[Key].destroy();
            responseSent = true;
        }
        delete readStreams[Key]; // Remove the read stream once finished
    });
}

This is the fucntion where it is showing the error but i m not sure if it really is the root cause.
You can view the whole code on my github if required :-
https://github.com/Dev771/CENACLE
I tried to limit the image request coming and also only resolving the last request that comes.
I enabled error handling in case their were any crash due to the stream but that didnt resolve the issue either.

what does this have to do with react or amazon-s3?

You are pipeing you sream into the response. In that moment the headers for the res are set and sent to the client, but responseSent is not set to true yet. That only happens, once the stream ends. Now when there is an error in your readStream, the error handler is called and tries to send res.json(...) to the client. This again wants to set the headers on res which is not allowed

@derpirscher Thank you for the response. I mistakenly entered React as the tag but i the function was using amazon s3 to recieve and send photo from their so i thought it may be occuring bcz of it I will Remove Those Tags. So why are these errors occuring and how can they be resolved? will setting the responseSent to true with piping solve the issue?
I am checking the error and I am recieving the error of
Error [TimeoutError]: Connection timed out after 120000ms
Which is coming from amazon s3 because it is unable to get the post detail for some reason.
Thank You
